# Vlan through ISR - Catalyst - Nexus doesn't work

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, cisco-catalyst, cisco-isr

I try to create a Vlan that route traffic through multiple Cisco Devices. For that I create a vlan13 on each device and setup a IP on the ISR and the Device attached to the Nexus also have a IP on the same subnet.

[image]

The setup is like this:

ISR 4451:

```
interface Vlan13
 description pfsense subnet
 ip address 10.1.1.49 255.255.255.240
end
interface Ethernet-Internal1/0/0
 description Trunk to internal switch module
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,11,13
 switchport mode trunk
end
```

SM-X

```
interface Vlan13
 ip address 10.1.1.51 255.255.255.240
end
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,13
 switchport mode trunk
end
interface GigabitEthernet0/52
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport protected
end
```

Nexus 3000

```
vlan 1,13
interface Ethernet1/16
  switchport access vlan 13
interface Ethernet1/47
```

I try to add `switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q` to the nexus config but the command is unavailable. Maybe this is the issue of my config. The Server attached to the Eth1/16 Port is configured with IP 10.1.1.50/28 and the IP 10.1.1.49 or 10.1.1.51 is not accessible from that server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

Ethernet1/47 was missing `switchport mode trunk`. The Nexus 3000 does not need an encapsulation command as it always encapsulates traffic on trunk ports.